# How to hide popover in Onsen Ui by clicking device back button?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I found following example [dropdown popover hide](http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/pJzPqE)

```
<ons-page>
<ons-toolbar ng-controller="DropdownController">
<div class="right">
  <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="popover.show($event);"><ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
</div>
<div class="center">Dropdown test</div>
</ons-toolbar>

 <p style="text-align: center; color: #999; padding-top: 100px;">Click the    upper right button to show dropdown.</p>
```

```
 <ons-template id="popover.html" >
 <ons-popover direction="down"style="height:50px;width:65px" cancelable >
<ons-list ng-controller="MyController">
  <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng- click="getPerson(1);hidePopover()">Admin</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-click="getPerson(2);hidePopover()">Seller</ons-list-item>      
</ons-list>
</ons-popover>
 </ons-template>



 var app = ons.bootstrap();

 app.controller('DropdownController', function($scope, myService) {
   ons.createPopover('popover.html').then(function(popover) {
    $scope.popover = popover;
  myService.setPopover($scope.popover);
    });
    });

   app.controller('MyController', function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.hidePopover = function() {
    $scope.popover = myService.getPopover();    
    $scope.popover.hide();
 }
 });

app.service("myService", function(){
 var sharedPopover

  var setPopover = function(pop){
   sharedPopover = pop;
 };

   var getPopover = function(){
   return sharedPopover;
 };

 return {
setPopover: setPopover,
  getPopover: getPopover,
 };
  });
```

It hides the popover when you click above it. I would like to hide the popover with the device back button (android).I tried to use `ng-device-backbutton="hidePopover()"` but it did not work. Any sugestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no experience with onsen, but i would try to add something like this to your controller `$scope.$on("backbutton", function () {
            //close your popover 
        });`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you choose to implement, i.e. via page API, overrides, etc. this reference should provide you with a starting point:

https://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#HandlingBackButton

This is an example and should do what you need, just know that it overrides all back button functionality for this page:

```
myPage.getDeviceBackButtonHandler().setListener(function(event) {
  // Call hide popover function referenced in your post
  hidePopver();
});
```

I think - though I haven't tested - that if you set the popover to `cancelable` then you will not have to add any backbutton functions and it will work as you intend by default behavior.

Edit:  Cancelable is for dialogues.  Might be another option to consider.